# How to set value in Bootstrap pincode input box?

Tags: jquery

I am using `bootstrap-pincode-input.js` library pincode type verification. I need 10 input box from 10 box, I want to display first 5 character as 'X' and should be displayed in the first 5 box. Next 4 will be entered by user and last one will be same as 'X'.
I have written below code in my `html` file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pincode-input1').pincodeInput({inputs:10});
});
```

I have no idea how to set value in box except 4 character.
Please suggest.

Comment: Give HTML code too

Comment: <input type="text" id="pincode-input1">

Comment: Why do you need 10 input boxes, when it can be done with just one?

Comment: check this one . http://fkranenburg.github.io/bootstrap-pincode-input/

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
$('#pincode-input1').pincodeInput({inputs:10,placeholders:"X X X X X     X"});
```

Read the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-pincode-input)

Comment: Placeholder is different thing.You can still enter character in that box and X will disappear.